# Null pointer error using Expandable list in Fragments

Tags: android

I'm trying to create an expandable list in one of the tab fragments. 
I'm getting the null pointer error, but I can't fix it...
The problem occurs in this section:
expandableListView.setAdapter(adapter);
Any help would be appreciated.

StackTrace (error):

```
      10-20 12:39:31.603: E/AndroidRuntime(3478): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-20 12:39:31.603: E/AndroidRuntime(3478): java.lang.NullPointerException
10-20 12:39:31.603: E/AndroidRuntime(3478):     at com.margaret.app.easypeasycooking.CountryAdapter.getGroupCount(CountryAdapter.java:119)
10-20 12:39:31.603: E/AndroidRuntime(3478):     at android.widget.ExpandableListConnector.getCount(ExpandableListConnector.java:397)
10-20 12:39:31.603: E/AndroidRuntime(3478):     at android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(ListView.java:463)
10-20 12:39:31.603: E/AndroidRuntime(3478):     at android.widget.ExpandableListView.setAdapter(ExpandableListView.java:599)
10-20 12:39:31.603: E/AndroidRuntime(3478):     at com.margaret.app.easypeasycooking.ShoppingList.onCreateView(ShoppingList.java:37)
10-20 12:39:31.603: E/AndroidRuntime(3478):     at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1695)
10-20 12:39:31.603: E/AndroidRuntime(3478):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:885)
10-20 12:39:31.603: E/AndroidRuntime(3478):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1057)
10-20 12:39:31.603: E/AndroidRuntime(3478):     at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
10-20 12:39:31.603: E/AndroidRuntime(3478):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1435)
10-20 12:39:31.603: E/AndroidRuntime(3478):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:441)
10-20 12:39:31.603: E/AndroidRuntime(3478):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
10-20 12:39:31.603: E/AndroidRuntime(3478):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-20 12:39:31.603: E/AndroidRuntime(3478):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-20 12:39:31.603: E/AndroidRuntime(3478):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
10-20 12:39:31.603: E/AndroidRuntime(3478):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-20 12:39:31.603: E/AndroidRuntime(3478):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
10-20 12:39:31.603: E/AndroidRuntime(3478):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
10-20 12:39:31.603: E/AndroidRuntime(3478):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
10-20 12:39:31.603: E/AndroidRuntime(3478):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

THe XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:id="@+id/shopping">

    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/elvShoppingList"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="400dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
    </ExpandableListView>

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
        android:text="RadioButton" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Please post the stack trace from logcat.  It shows **exactly** where the error is.  You should also learn to use the debugger.  NullPointerExceptions are very easy to find and fix and the debugger will enable you to do so in minutes.

Comment: Can you post the stack trace?

Comment: @AdamToth Just added the stack trace.

Comment: @Simon - THanks for a hint. Will try to use it. Haven't thought about it.

Comment: This is not a NullPointer exception! 
expandableListView = (ExpandableListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.shopping); 
this is clearly a RelativeLayout and you are casting it to ExpandableListView

Comment: I have changed the expandableListView = (ExpandableListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.shopping); --> and ran it; I have attached the XML and the updated stack. You can see now that this is null pointer exception error....

Answer (score 1):

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.ExpandableListView
10-20 10:53:08.892: E/AndroidRuntime(2636):     at com.margaret.app.easypeasycooking.ShoppingList.onCreateView(ShoppingList.java:37)
```

At `ShoppingList` line 37, you are trying to cast a `RelativeLayout` to an `ExandableListView`.

In this line, `expandableListView = (ExpandableListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.shopping);` **R.id.shopping** is referring to a RelativeLayout, and not your list view.

Edit your question to include the XML and we can confirm that.

Comment: I have changed theexpandableListView = (ExpandableListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.shopping); --> and ran it;                    I have attached the XML and the updated stack. YOu can see now that this is null pointer exception error....